# In the Google analytics, how to customize data of different pages?

Tags: google-analytics

In the Google analytics, I am sending event,pages visit information but I want to customized information pages wise in particular page how many events are fire. Please How I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand the question, but you have a Page report in the Content / Events section, does this help ?

It shows on which page has happened which event.